# How to "calculate" correctly the liquid column height in not "simple" capacities?

Tags: pressure, fluid-statics

As I was told on a youtube lesson, to calculate the hydrostatic pressure on the bottom of a capacity, that's on the picture below, I need to use the **h1 height**(see that formula on the picture). And it totally confuses me, because as I think, the hydrostatic pressure formula in that case must be looking like:

##### p=F/S, where F=P=mg, where m=Vρ, where V=S*((h1+h2)/2), and then:

#### ↓

#### p=ρgS*((h1+h2)/2)/S

### ↓

### p=ρg*((h1+h2)/2)

[image]

---

And of course, (h1+h2)/2 < h1, so:

1. **where am I wrong** ?
2. **What liquid column height value do I actually need to take here to calculate the correct value of the hydrostatic pressure at the bottom ?**

Answer (score 1):

The pressure at the bottom of a column of fluid is
$ P = P_0 + \rho g h$

An important bit of that is $P_0$, the pressure at the top of the column.  For the bit on the right (with the open top), we know the top is either 1 atm (if we care about absolute pressure) or 0 (if we care about gauge pressure).

But on the left, the column is constrained by the container.  This container is providing a pressure downward.  If the container were not rigid enough, the surface could fail and the water would no longer be in this shape.

So the pressure at the bottom of the left column is the same even though the fluid height is different because of the pressure from the container.

---

> where F=P=mg

This only accounts for the pressure *due to the mass of the fluid*.  The total may be greater due to additional pressure from above the column.

In your problem you can't just look at the mass of the fluid to find the pressure because some pressure is coming from the container as well.

---

> I also don't understand why I "can't look at the mass" if I'm about only the hydrostatic pressure

Because that may only be one part.  Let's imagine a scenario.  You put 1kg of water into a container with a 1 square meter floor.  You can calculate that the pressure at the bottom will be F/A = 9.8Pa.

Now we put a lid on top of the container so it sits right on top of the water.  Then we squeeze the container tight.  If you measure the pressure at the bottom of the container, it will no longer read 9.8Pa, but something much greater.  But the mass of the water hasn't changed at all!    Why?  Because the container is pushing on the top of the water.

The same thing is happening at the top of the h2 column.

Comment: Ohh, you didn't understand my question. I wasn't asking about the difference between pressure at "left and right columns", of course they have the same value.

Comment: Then why do you care about h2?  Why aren't you calculating the pressure at the bottom just with h1?

Comment: Because that's not correct as I think, and I showed it here:
p=F/S, where F=P=mg, where m=Vρ, where V=S*((h1+h2)/2), and then:
↓
p=ρgS*((h1+h2)/2)/S
↓
p=ρg*((h1+h2)/2)

Comment: I addressed that in the answer.  It is not true that $P = \rho hg = mg/A$ in all cases.  When external pressures (like from the container above h2) are present, then the pressure is greater.  You need to account for the $P_0$ term.  Over h1 it is zero and can be ignored.  Over h2 it is not zero and must be accounted for.

Comment: Thank you for continuing answering and helping me. Actually I haven't passed yet topics about "atm", "absolute/gauge pressures", even if I've googled it just now. So I don't quite understand what you're trying to tell. I also don't understand why I "can't look at the mass" if I'm about only the hydrostatic pressure, coming from the water to the bottom of the capacity.

Comment: Added another bit.